# This guy MAKES vlogging HIS LIVING? (Expression)

Tags: phrase-usage, expressions

Let's say you have seen tons of Youtube videos made by a particular guy. As we all know, there is money earned out of it, then you reacted to his way of earning money and you say:

> Oh my, this guy really **makes** youtube vlogging **his living?!**.

Is this a correct expression? Because what I usually see in example sentences is the "make a living" phrase, but it seems to me "**his**" is more appropriate than "**a**" in this situation, that's why I've changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a sense of "to make a living" that means make just enough money to survive on. It probably excludes luxuries.

> make a living idiom
>
> Definition of make a living  : to earn the money
>   one needs to pay for housing, food, etc.
>
> He made a living by working as a cook.
>   https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make%20a%20living

**Example**

*You work as a waiter don't you?*

*Yes.*

*Does it pay well?*

*Not really but it's a living.*

---

There is perhaps less stigma attached to making something 'your' living.

> Oh my, this guy really makes YouTube-vlogging his living!

I'd say that is perfectly correct.

Another example, (with a different meaning), might be:

> Oh my, this guy really makes YouTube-vlogging his life's work! He's totally dedicated to it.

Comment: Excellent answer, but I wonder why you "hyphenated" the youtube and vlogging... I don't quite get that...

Comment: It's a good question. I suppose it's to distinguish from "Oh my, this guy really makes YouTube [by] vlogging his living!"  Admittedly that version makes no sense but as we read, we can't always predict the grammar that is coming. For me there is less of a mental load if you make the grammar clear as soon as possible. Maybe this needs to be a separate question. Some people may agree with me, others may disagree.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a more idiomatic sentence:

> Oh my, this guy really makes his living youtube vlogging?!

"Make a living" means approximately "earn an income". The phrase is not used as "make some profession their living" but rather "make their living by some profession".